# How to correctly format 'data' for HighChart

Tags: c#, javascript, highcharts

I have the following code -

**C#**

```
string data = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", listOfInts));
string script = string.Format("chart('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}');",
startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute, chartTitle, data);

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "chart", script, true);
```

**Javascript**

```
series: [{
             type: 'area',
             name: 'Count:',
             pointInterval:  3600 * 1000,
             pointStart: Date.UTC(startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute),
             data: intsAsJSArray

        }]
```

Where `inrtAsJSArray` = `"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"`.

This breaks the graphing function and I have realised that it is due to `data` being in the wrong format.

However if I hard code the `data` section like -

```
series: [{
             type: 'area',
             name: 'Count:',
             pointInterval:  3600 * 1000,
             pointStart: Date.UTC(startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute),
             data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

        }]
```

This works, how can I reconfigure `intASJarray` to be accepted into the series?

Comment: So intASJarray is not printed? Have you tried to convert intASJarray into JSON and then use in highcharts?

Comment: intASJarray is formatted in the C# - string data = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", listOfInts)); where data is intASJarray. This works when using a veiwstate and calling it like <% =intASJarray%>

Comment: As a result it is string, not array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse the string to an array

```
var str = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]";

var trim = str.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "");

var data = trim.split(",");

data = data.map(function (d) {
    return +d;
});

console.log(data);
```

here is the demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnmT2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `RegisterStartupScript` but the crux of it is that your `intASJarray` ends up a javascript string instead of an array.

Try:

```
string script = string.Format("chart('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}',{6});",
   startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute, chartTitle, data);
```

Notice I've dropped the quotes on the string format `{6}` argument.  You might need to do this for the data parts as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you target browsers that support [JSON.parse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript), you can parse the string like this:

```
  series: [{
         type: 'area',
         name: 'Count:',
         pointInterval:  3600 * 1000,
         pointStart: Date.UTC(startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute),
         data: JSON.parse(intsAsJSArray)

    }]
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/MnsuS/